# HTML/CSS/JS: How to Disable CSS Hover with Clicking? And Enable Again?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, hover

Sorry for poor English, it is not my first language.

I have made a toggle button which shows specific information by clicking it(javascript here). 
This button has CSS:hover and I want to disable it when I click the toggle button.
And CSS:hover function needs to be back when user hovers the button again.

Is there any way to disable CSS:hover functionally?
Please let me know if you need more info to it.

Current Javascript

```
let logStyle = document.getElementById("log").style;
let levelStyle = document.getElementById("level").style;
let log = document.getElementById("log");
let level = document.getElementById("level");

odium.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
  logStyle.display = "block";
  logStyle.animation = "fadein .3s";
  levelStyle.display = "block";
  levelStyle.animation = "fadein .3s";
}, false);

odium.addEventListener("mouseout", function (event) {
    logStyle.display = "none";
    levelStyle.display = "none";
}, false); 

odium.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  log.classList.toggle('active');
  level.classList.toggle('active');
}, false);
```

Toggle button CSS

```
#header nav img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
}

#log.active{
  display: flex !important;
  animation: fadein .3s !important;
}
```

Current HTML

```
        <header id="header">
          <nav> 
            <ul>
              <li>
                <img id="symbol1" src="assets/css/images/symbol-odium.png" style="cursor: pointer;"/><span
                  id="level"
                ></span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <p id="nowValue" class="nowValue"></p>
          <div id="log" class="log">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="oneHundred" class="btn" onclick="valueToggle100(); return false;"></a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="eighty" class="btn" onclick="valueToggle80(); return false;">230104</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: Please also post your HTML and put all code into a snippet/fiddle on the question. Sounds like you can use disabled attribute then remove that when you want hover to work again.

Comment: Is it a must to write the hover effect in js? Because i think a simple css `ClassName:hover:not(:active) {/*whatever effects you need*/}` can do what you want here.

Comment: @NathanielFlick Um, you can check it here https://odium.kr , try to click the symbol image on the center, then I guess you will understand what I meant

Comment: @Eezo Actually I am trying to disable hover when user click so that they can realize that their interaction is working

Comment: @mmd Uhm yeah? My code indicate that it will have hover effect unless you click the button - which then will be in state active and won't display the effect until you stop holding down the mouse button. You can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/j35cs249) if it did what you want

Comment: Use the "disabled" property on the button and the hover is taken care of. No need to do fancy CSS for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to understand what you need: a two- or tri-state action button.

1. hover: grow to look elevated
2. active: shrink to original elevation
3. focus: [OPTIONAL] shrink to look pressed elevation

Option 3) has only real effect when the element is a `<button>` or an `<input type="button">`. In general: *an element that can receive focus*, where buttons seem the most logical choice.

The **snippet** shows some simplified code of how it's done, with a bit more subtle action:

```css
.button_img { cursor: pointer }

.button_img:hover              { transform: scale(1.03) }
.button_img:active:not(:focus) { transform: scale(1)    }
.button_img:focus              { transform: scale(0.98) }
```

```html
<img class="button_img" src="https://picsum.photos/74?random">
```